# How to find the size of a file in a For Each Loop Container in SSIS?

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I am trying to find the size of a file in my FELC. I have used the following code but I keep getting an error. This is the code in my script task.

```
     Public Sub Main()

    Dim LoopFilePath As String = Dts.Variables("User::vvarcharsource").Value.ToString

    Dim infoReader As System.IO.FileInfo
    infoReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(LoopFilePath)
    Dts.Variables("User::vintsize").Value = infoReader.Length
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

I use one read variable vvarcharsource that is of type varchar and one readwrite variable vintsize that is of type double.

The error I'm getting is:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting datatype of User::vintsize to varchar solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

i do not entirely get what you are trying to do here. 
What is this "DTS variable" consting of ? 
Also i do not know what you mean with FELC 
(google says First English Lutheran church  or other stuff so an explanation would be good ;)  )

Maybe you split it into more single functions to see where exactly it fails, it is gonna be hard to get what happens at the moment

I'd put the filesize-part into something like this (you might even want to build a function that returns the values you want)

```
Public Sub GetFileInfo(ByVal Path As String)

    If System.IO.File.Exists(Path) Then
        Dim Fi As New FileInfo(Path)
        Dim FileSize As Long
        Dim FilsizeInt As Integer
        FileSize = Fi.Length
        FilsizeInt = CInt(Math.Round(FileSize / 1024))
        MsgBox("filesize is about " & FilsizeInt & " kb")
    Else
        MsgBox("file not found")
    End If

End Sub
```

hth

Comment: the code is part of a script task in my SSIS package.